# Efficient Way to Iterate and Producing Output in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following datas,

```
let response =[
  {
    "14714733": [
      "Android Testing-1",
      "Test special manual",
      "Test Manual",
      "SECESC"
    ]
  },
  {
    "10110133": [
      "Android Testing-1",
      "SECESC"
    ]
  }
]


let shipment =[
  {
    "masterDocumentNumber": "14714733"
  },
  {
    "masterDocumentNumber": "10110133",
  }
]
```

And

```
let flagIns=[
  {
    "fieldValue": "SECESC",
    "fieldDescription": "Security Escort"
  },
  {
    "fieldValue": "INS",
    "fieldDescription": "Inspection"
  }
]
```

How to iterate and add Corresponding response data in to shipment data as follows,

### Desired output

```
let shipment =[
  {
    "masterDocumentNumber": "14714733",
    "instructions":[
       {"index":0,"instruction":"Android Testing-1"},
       {"index":1,"instruction":"Test special manual"},
       {"index":2,"instruction":"Test Manual"},
       {"index":3,"instruction":"Security Escort"}
     ]
  },
  {
    "masterDocumentNumber": "10110133",
     "instructions":[
       {"index":0,"instruction":"Android Testing-1"},
       {"index":1,"instruction":"Security Escort"}
     ]
  }
]
```

Note that if flagIns has same data in response then it need to be replaced with it's description.

Comment: Try using .filter or .find. Javascript array methods will help here.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. If you don't know where to start, I would suggest hiring a contractor.

Comment: i tried in a way that looping 3 for loop inside each. i also got the out put as well . But i like to know is there any efficient way other than that

Comment: Could you post your solution as code sample? That way improvement would be easier to check.

Comment: How can we suggest a more efficient method if we don't know the way you're doing it now?

Comment: Is this a situation where reduce() would come in handy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a function similar to this.. it appears you just need to match up keys and values from the different objects..

```js
function aggregate(response, shipment, flagIns) {
  return shipment.map(({ masterDocumentNumber }) => {
    let output = { masterDocumentNumber, instructions: [] }
    let res = response.find(r => masterDocumentNumber in r);
    if (res) {
      res[masterDocumentNumber].forEach((r, i) => {
        let ins = flagIns.find(fi => fi.fieldValue === r);
        output.instructions.push({
          index: i,
          instruction: ins ? ins.fieldDescription : r
        })
      })
    }
    return output;
  });
}

const response = [
  {
    "14714733": [
      "Android Testing-1",
      "Test special manual",
      "Test Manual",
      "SECESC"
    ]
  },
  {
    "10110133": ["Android Testing-1", "SECESC"]
  }
];

const shipment = [
  {
    masterDocumentNumber: "14714733"
  },
  {
    masterDocumentNumber: "10110133"
  }
];

const flagIns = [
  {
    fieldValue: "SECESC",
    fieldDescription: "Security Escort"
  },
  {
    fieldValue: "INS",
    fieldDescription: "Inspection"
  }
];

console.log(aggregate(response, shipment, flagIns));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let shipment =[];
//create array
response.map((res)=>{
  //get keys
let key=Object.keys(res)
  //loop in instructions
let instructions=[];
res[key].map((val,i)=>{
let inst ={
      "index":i,
      "instruction":val
    }
    instructions.push(inst)

  })
  let m={
    "masterDocumentNumber":key,
    "instructions":instructions
  }
  shipment.push(m)
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(shipment))
```

Answer (score 0):

First flatten the response and flagIns array of objects and then iterate over the shipment array to get the desired output.

```js
let response =[
  {
    "14714733": [
      "Android Testing-1",
      "Test special manual",
      "Test Manual",
      "SECESC"
    ]
  },
  {
    "10110133": [
      "Android Testing-1",
      "SECESC"
    ]
  }
]


let shipment =[
  {
    "masterDocumentNumber": "14714733"
  },
  {
    "masterDocumentNumber": "10110133",
  }
]


let flagIns=[
  {
    "fieldValue": "SECESC",
    "fieldDescription": "Security Escort"
  },
  {
    "fieldValue": "INS",
    "fieldDescription": "Inspection"
  }
]

const responseRes = response.reduce(function (acc, item) {
  return Object.assign(acc, item);
}, {});

// responseRes
// {
//   '10110133': [ 'Android Testing-1', 'SECESC' ],
//   '14714733': [
//     'Android Testing-1',
//     'Test special manual',
//     'Test Manual',
//     'SECESC'
//   ]
// }

const flagInsRes = flagIns.reduce(function (acc, item) {
  return Object.assign(acc, {
    [item.fieldValue]: item.fieldDescription});
}, {});

// flagInsRes
// { SECESC: 'Security Escort', INS: 'Inspection' }

const shipmentRes = shipment.map(obj => {
  const temp = {};
  temp.masterDocumentNumber = obj.masterDocumentNumber
  temp.instructions = responseRes[obj.masterDocumentNumber]
  .map((item, index) => {
    return {
      "index":index,
      "instruction":flagInsRes[item] ? flagInsRes[item] : item}
    });
  return temp;
});

console.log(shipmentRes);
```